# Loading self signed cert to HttpsUrlConnection breaks default CA cert validation

Tags: android, ssl, android-volley, httpsurlconnection

I'm trying to load a BKS with `HttpsUrlConnection` and with following code it worked, however it broke the default CA cert validation with my other servers.

```
try {
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory
            .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
    InputStream in = ctw.getResources()
            .openRawResource(R.raw.bks);
    ks.load(in, "password".toCharArray());
    in.close();
    tmf.init(ks);
    TrustManager[] tm = tmf.getTrustManagers();

    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory
            .getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    kmf.init(ks, "password".toCharArray());

    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tm, null);

    HttpsURLConnection
            .setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {

                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname,
                        SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                }
            });

    HttpsURLConnection
            .setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The error I get is:

```
com.android.volley.NoConnectionError:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException:
Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

I am using `Volley` library for network requests. Is my code wrong or should I be modifying `Volley` library?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I did was create a `CompositeTrustManager` that could check multiple sources, both a self-signed cert and the default CAs. That's hidden behind [the `TrustManagerBuilder` API](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security/blob/master/TrustManagerBuilder.markdown) in [my CWAC-Security library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security/). You would use code like:

```
new TrustManagerBuilder(this)
  .selfSigned(R.raw.bks, "password".toCharArray())
  .or()
  .useDefault();
```

then call `build()` to get the `TrustManager[]` that handles both your self-signed cert and the default CAs.

As it stands, your code is *replacing* the stock `TrustManager[]` with one tied to your BKS store.

Another approach would be to catch the failure and retry with a connection that lacks your custom `TrustManager[]`.